# Uart doesn't work after waking up from stop mode in stm32f4

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

I am using `STOP` mode to save power and also deinitialize `GPIO` to achieve maximum power saving. In this case current consumption goes below 1mA. I am using `UART` `Rx` pin as external interrupt to wake up board from `STOP` mode. The board does wake up but `UART` or other peripheral like `DCMI` doesn't work. Following is my code.

```
void MX_GPIO_Deinit()
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    /* Disable GPIOs clock */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_DISABLE();
}

void stopMode(void)
{
  HAL_SuspendTick();
  MX_GPIO_Deinit();
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF8_UART4;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);
}

void resumeStopMode(void)
{
    SystemClock_Config();
    HAL_ResumeTick();
    MX_GPIO_Init();

    HAL_UART_MspInit(&huart4);
    HAL_I2C_MspInit(&hi2c2);
    HAL_DCMI_MspInit(&hdma_dcmi);
    HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);
    MX_DMA_Init();
    MX_UART4_Init();
    MX_I2C2_Init();
    MX_DCMI_Init();
    MX_TIM1_Init();

    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
}

int getChar()
{
   uint8_t InputData = 0;
   TimmingDelay = 50000;
   while (TimmingDelay !=0)
   {
       if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart4, UART_FLAG_ORE))
           __HAL_UART_CLEAR_OREFLAG(&huart4);

       if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart4, UART_FLAG_RXNE))
       {
           InputData = huart4.Instance->DR & 0x1FF;
           return InputData;
       }
   }
   return -1;
}

void main(void)
{
    stopMode()
    resumeStopMode() /* woken up by uart interrupt*/
    int receivedByte = 0;
    receivedByte = getChar() /* This line doesn't work after waking it goes into stop mode */
}
```

Since I deinitialize all `GPIO` I am not able to to debug. How can I make `UART` work properly after waking up from `STOP` mode.

Comment: `MX_UART4_Init` already calls `HAL_UART_MspInit` from inside `HAL_UART_Init`, no need to call them explicitly. You have to show your configuration of huart4, so `MX_UART4_Init` and if you use, any DMA and such. Any reason why don't you call hal function from inside `getChar()`? Does something like the following `int getChar()
{ char c; return HAL_UART_Receive(&huart, &c, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK : c ? EOF; }` work? To be able to debug, you could left out SWI pins from deinitialization.

Comment: Thanks for your  comment. Yes I can remove `HAL_UART_MspInit`. The SWI pins and UART are on same `GPIOA`.

Comment: So they are? So don't set SWI pins to analog, so you can debug.

Comment: I found that  the 1st byte that board gets after waking from `STOP` mode is corrupt and if we ignore 1st byte then after that we get correct data on `UART` . But `I2C` and `DCMI` doesn't work. Is there any proper way to reset all of these after waking up from `STOP` mode?

Answer (score 0):

There is a wake-up latency associated with STOP mode to allow the HSI RC oscillator to wake up and potentially flash and the internal regulator. If the first byte is corrupt then it is most likely that it is a result of this latency.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
          HAL_UART_MspInit(&huart4);
          __HAL_UART_DISABLE(&huart4);
          __HAL_UART_ENABLE(&huart4);
```

but following do not work.

```
          HAL_UART_Init(&huart4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into almost this exact same issue and here was my solution (keep in mind I'm using UART2):

```
    HAL_UART_MspInit(&huart2);
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();
```

The reason that just calling the normal `MX_USART2_UART_Init()` function doesn't work is because the UART peripheral has state and wont re-initialize clocks if its state doesn't think it needs to:

```
    Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_uart.c

    308 HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Init(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
    309 {
    .
    .
    .
    327   if (huart->gState == HAL_UART_STATE_RESET)
    328   {
    .
    .
    .
    343     /* Init the low level hardware : GPIO, CLOCK */
    344     HAL_UART_MspInit(huart);
```